# How to lock the position and size of a text-frame in InDesign CS6?

Tags: adobe-indesign, text, master-page

How to lock the position and size of a text-frame in InDesign CS6?

I would like to lock those properties in each page in Indesign. Sometimes the designers get wrong and drag and drop the text frame without noticing.

Then we have to remove the page and create again. If this is not done when I update the master will not update the size and position of the text frame

Answer (score 4):

Go to General Preferences <kbd>cmd</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> and deselect Prevent Selection of Locked Objects. That's it.

Comment: And all a user needs to do go back to the preferences and uncheck that option to edit what you are trying to prevent them from editing. In addition, that preference won't travel with the document. It's an app pref, not a doc pref.

Comment: Are you sure that after that I can edit it's contents?

Answer (score 2):

Lock the text box/frame (Ctrl+L), then go to preferences (Ctrl+K) and UNCHECK 'Prevent Selection of Locked Objects'. This actually means Selecet (& Editing), so the position is locked and editing is not.

Answer (score 0):

Seems this is more a business control issue.

Indesign allows locking of objects via the **object menu**. However, if you lock a text frame you can't make any changes at all to it, including the internal text. In addition, it's a very simple thing to unlock anything. There's no method to lock only position and size but allow text editing.

Comment: of course I would need to change the text into the text frame

Comment: That's my point. You can not lock a text frame but still edit the text. What you want can't be done.