# Interactive template for making printable document

Tags: pdf, template-design, microsoft-word

I'm creating a template for a simple printable document where the user should be able to change the placeholder text and example images. These user won't have access to any fancy program like InDesign.

The documents will contain information about different projects and each project leader should be able to add project information and a photo of the project group.

I'm thinking of either creating an interactive pdf using InDesing or a Word template using Word (duh).

The interactive pdf seems more elegant but is it possible to change photos? The Word way is maybe easier but I don't want the user to be able to change fonts, size, text placement etc...

I found [this question](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29590/how-to-best-create-templates-for-clients-to-edit-the-content-copy) which addresses the issue but does anybody have any different ideas? Maybe there are som online web tools for doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: Howabout latex or a web solution?

Comment: I don't want to force the user to install any new software (Office and Adobe Reader is ok) so I'm not sure about LaTeX. A web solution could absolutely work though. Any suggestions?

Comment: Well you can't do anything with Acrobat then. It's called Acrobat reader because you can only view files. You need beefier versions of Acrobat to be able to edit stuff.

Comment: I guess that makes sense. Although it's possible to edit (or rather add) text.

Comment: [CK editor](http://ckeditor.com/demo) could probably be salvaged for this purpose. The server could then use whatever system to produce the final print.

Comment: This could probably be a long winding approach, but the user will require only a web-browser to make changes. Why not serve the template as a web page. For print purposes use a [print-specific css](http://alistapart.com/article/goingtoprint). Let the user access the web page in browser and edit objects that you want them to edit. There are few ways to accomplish. You could either build the entire thing using PHP or other tools that you are good at or use Wordpress with limited access control.

Comment: Thanks @bbh, it turned out that the project had a Wordpress page that I could use.