# Lock the position of text box on the artboard but NOT the contents so text remains editable

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I am using Illustrator 2018 on Windows.

Is it possible to lock the position (and if possible the size) of text box on the artboard but NOT the contents so text remains editable?

I find that when working on a text box I move it by accident often with out realising which causes all of the other text in the box to be out of place with the other elements in my design.

After searching on here I have found a thread about this issue but within Indesign so I tried the solution given for Indesign but it does not work in Illustrator 2018.

The solution offered for Indesign is:

> Lock the text box/frame (Ctrl+L), then go to preferences (Ctrl+K) and
>   UNCHECK 'Prevent Selection of Locked Objects'. This actually means
>   Select (& Editing), so the position is locked and editing is not.

I know how to lock a object on a layer but once locked it is not editable so I wonder if there is a solution similar to one above but Illustrator specific?

Comment: See this Stack Exchange [answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/16597/how-to-lock-the-position-and-size-of-a-text-frame-in-indesign-cs6)

Comment: That is exactly the thread that I quoted above - it is Indesgn specific and does not work in Illustrator (if it does I can not get it to do so).

Comment: A text frame is just a type area. You can't lock it while keeping the text editable